# In Expo when I build Android (The `keytool` utility was not found)

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am writing project in React Native with Expo.

Tried to Build it.

when I type command expo build:android

I choose `apk type`

then it asks me if you want to have us generate keystore one for you?
I chose `auto generate` and this happens

[image]

I have Java SDK installed even double checked keytool.exe is there. I can generate manually.
but how can I solve this?

P.S Already did in Environment variable I wrote java path in PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure jre is installed.

```
cd /path/to/jre/bin/folder
```

As keytool file is present in the bin folder of jre, give path till bin as in the command above.

Then you can do:

```
keytool -genkey -alias aliaskeyname -keyalg RSA -keystore C:\mykeystore
```

The additional option -keystore will help you to specify the path where you want the generated self signed certificate.

Comment: so this is actually manual making keystool?